# How to resolve Runlog error on Chainlink node

Tags: oracles, chainlink

I keep getting the below error when I request data from my node.

```
error": "rejecting job bd25ae01d8604b268abfbfa764399511 with payment 100000000000000000 below minimum threshold (1000000000000000000)"
```

I haven't specified a minimum payment in the bridge (its all set to 0) so I don't understand what the minimum threshold referred to is. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to increase the amount of Link paid to the oracle by the contract. 1 Link works